# Finding all objects with a jquery plugin applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get a list of all objects using a specified plugin? I know i can add a class to each element when it's applied but i was wondering if there was an existing way...

thanks,

Comment: Class is the normal way of doing this.

Comment: It really depends on the plugin, whether they've built in functionality to recognize ifActive. class is the best way to do this universally, and its super low overhead, so go that direction.

Comment: Several plugins set something in the element's `.data()`. What plugin are you using and what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks, this is generally for my own plugins, so i can easily destroy/re-apply the plugins if needed, and so when writing new ones in future i build this ability in

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without using classes, you might want to sniff the plugin calls, like this:

```
var elemsCalled = []; // this will contain all elements upon which the plugin has been called

var orig = $.fn.somePlugin;
$.fn.somePlugin = function() {
    elementsCalled.push(this);
    return orig.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); // for chaining, as Alnitak noted
}
```

Now, whenever you call `$.somePlugin`, the element you call it on would be added to `elemsCalled`.

Comment: Sneaky idea :) Just wondering (I'm probably forgetting something), but why are you slicing the arguments starting at `1` and not `0`?

Comment: Oh, whoops, that was my bad. Thanks for the catch. :-)

Comment: Oh haha okay, I didn't know if there was something special passed to a method that I was forgetting, or something :)

Comment: actually `.slice` will default to 0 if you omit that argument.  And you should `return` the result of `.apply`

Comment: Oh, will it, Alnitak? Didn't know that! Cool.

Comment: @Alnitak While that might work, I don't think it's standard or should be used for that reason. I don't see anything here about what to do if it's omitted: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10 . Maybe I'm crazy or forgetting something

Comment: @Alnitak At the same time, I see MDN using it without that `start` for this exact thing - getting a copy of the `arguments`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice (at/near the bottom), so I'm not sure which is "better" to use.

Comment: @Ian yes, it appears you're technically correct.  FWIW, in ES5 browsers you don't need to call `.slice` at all - you can just do `return orig.apply(this, arguments)`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville you still need to add a `return`, otherwise your monkey-patched plugin won't chain.

Comment: Also true, thanks. I was going to do that but got distracted and forgot to. :p

Comment: @Alnitak Now is that because `apply` *used to* require an array, not an array-like object? Good point though :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Actually, I think you'd need `return orig.apply(all that stuff);` - because you don't know what the plugin will return, and can't assume it will return `this`

Comment: @Ian ES5 does say that the second arg to `.apply` can be _array like_.  Earlier versions did require a real array.